# How to get different ethereum address for deposit functionality like binance

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I want create deposit functionality like binance but i dont know how to create different ethereum address . If i use create2 then how much it will cost .

Answer (score 0):

You can use any software to create a valid Ethereum public and private key pairs - web3, etherjs, keythereum, etc it really does not matter which software you're using. If you want to copy the binance deposit logic the most important thing to do is to generate the pair of keys when a user create his account *( or even better when the user wants to deposit for the first time )* and bind this pair exactly for this user *( like a database relation )*.

Now you will have a list ( database ) of public and private key pairs, next thing to do is to add event watchers for the incoming deposits exactly for the public keys in your database or once in a while check the blockchain history if the public addresses have been deposited in the past.

**The list with the private keys must be secure as hell**, because these keys will be the only accesses to whatever the users have been depositing.

Comment: But i dont think binance work that way they dont create address by their own . Instead they create Mask address and then transfer ethereum to that wallet address

Comment: What do you mean by "Mask" address? They are creating multiple "deposit" addresses which are unique per user and then once in a while combine the assets from them into other wallets.

Comment: Not sure but if you about coinbase commerce. Every time you make a payment they give you unique address and once a payment made to that address they tranfer amount to the owner address